# How many different ways to arrange 800 hydrogen atoms and 200 deuterium atoms to a specific way?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I'm recently reading a textbook about thermodynamics from the probability point of view. It mentioned a probability distribution, where there are 800 H atoms and 200 D atoms, and they collide with a given catalyst in the reaction chamber,

800 H + 200 D ---> 320 H2 + 20 D2 + 160HD

For this specific arrangement, 320 H2 + 20 D2 + 160 HD
There should be 7.35 × (10^214) ways to arrange. Also, without the given specified arrangement, by completely random, there are 6.6 × (10^215) different ways to arrange these molecules.

How it is done? Please show details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

There are 200 H atoms out of which 160 H atoms become HD which can be done $800C160$ ways and the rest of them become H2 similarly there are $200C160$ ways of selecting 160 D atoms to become HD. Hence the total number of ways will be $800C160 * 200C160 $ which of the order $10^{214}$. But I didn't understand what do you mean by without specified arrangement.